# What would an implementation of this Neural Network look like?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I'm relatively new to neural networks and was wondering what an implementation of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Bing_Zhao23/publication/271546169_Study_on_NNPID-based_adaptive_control_for_electro-optical_gyro_stabilized_platform/links/56e745f408ae438aab881bab.pdf) would look like. More specifically, how are the correct values of Kp, Ki, and Kd determined at run time so it can be back propagated?

Answer (score 1):

In the paper there is a diagram of the network showing how there are 3 outputs which share features but have their own set of associated weights. Back propagation works by only looking at one output at a time. 
[image: Network Architecture]